# Why is the font in firefox embeded pdf reader so ugly?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I got the problem that the fonts in the firefox (ver. 25.0) looks really ugly and are a pain to read.
When I save the PDF and open it with adobe reader, it's ok.

Here's a screenshot which shows a PDF in 100% scale.

[image]

Comment: There is no question in your post. Could you please rephrase it to be a question?

Comment: does this happen with all the pdfs or some pdf on a particular website ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try toggling **Use hardware acceleration when available** in Firefox **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Options** > **Advanced** > [General](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/advanced-settings-browsing-network-updates-encryption), restart Firefox and check.

Another option you could try is to toggle **Allow pages to choose their own fonts, ...** in Firefox **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Options** > Content > [Advanced](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/settings-fonts-languages-pop-ups-javascript#w_fonts-dialog) and reload the PDF file. The corresponding [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) option is [browser.display.use_document_fonts](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.). Please note that this also affects fonts display in web pages.

[See also the fourth comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=872471). It looks like the improvement efforts are still ongoing and would be incrementally merged in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Firefox 111.0.1 (64-bit) for Linux.  Firefox PDF reader uses that ugly font with bad kerning.  Other readers like Zathura and Chrome PDF reader display the fonts fine (or use a substitute that isn't that terrible).

This only occurred with PDF files that use fonts that are not embedded in them.  To check the fonts of a PDF file see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/614694/7498073).

So a workaround for this issue is to embed the missing fonts to the PDF file.  One way to do it is using Ghostscript: `gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dEmbedAllFonts=true input.pdf`. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13131101/7498073) for more details.